# Single and Double Quotes Problems

Tags: php

I was struggling with escaping double and single quotes with addslashes() and stripslashes()... in a mini web application that just inserts values and retrieves those values back out in a form to edit, and a general page to view the attributes. Finally I settled on this function to change single and double quotes:

```
function fixQuotes($string) {
    $string = str_replace("'", '&apos;', $string);
    $string = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Since I don't have any details for you as for what was happening before using this method, I can't really ask what was wrong. Rather, I would like to know if there are any drawbacks of using this function to replace single and double quotes with the html entities.

Comment: First of all why and where you are replacing double quot to single quot??

Comment: try htmlspecialchars()

Comment: I'm replacing the quotes on strings that are going into a mysql database. I tried using stripslashes and addslashes, but it didn't work on my form page. The stripslashes part anyway.

Comment: And @Nes, I'm not replacing double quotes to single quotes, or vice-versa. I'm replacing each to their respective html entities.

Comment: _“I'm replacing the quotes on strings that are going into a mysql database.”_ – that’s nonsense. Please read up on how data should _really_ be handled before putting it into the context of a database query.

Comment: Read http://kunststube.net/escapism for an overview of what you're trying to do here and why.

Comment: @CBroe how is this nonsense? The function is basically replacing quotes with their entities, and inserting them into a database. It doesn't seem like nonsense, and, I mean, it's working on the application. I'm not saying you're wrong, but can you clarify or at least give me a source to read up on "how data should really be handled". As you can tell, I'm a PHP and MySQL noob, and I'm trying to learn more about this.

Comment: _“The function is basically replacing quotes with their entities, and inserting them into a database”_ – and what would be the _purpose_ of this replacing?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to avoid the escaping altogether because stripslashes() didn't work. If the values are saved as entities there doesn't seem to be any issue with the SQL statement that is enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just magically "fix" quotes without knowing where the data is going to.

1. When you insert data into a database, escape it with the database API's escape function. If you're using the legacy MySQL API (which you should not be in new code as it is deprecated), use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). If you're using the MySQL-improved API, use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). If you're using PDO, use [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), or [execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) with the `input_parameters` parameter, or [quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).
2. When you echo text to an HTML page, use [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).